# Write a program that calculates the average of all the numbers stored in the file

Tags: python

```py
'''
Average Number 
'''

def main ():
    import sys
    try:
        NumberTxt = open("numbers.txt", "r")
    except IOError as e:
        print ("Non-numeric data found in the file   /n press enter" )
    except (ValueError):
        print( "Non-numberic data found in the file /n press enter")
    else:
        TotalNumber = 0
        NumbersOfLines = 0
        line = NumberTxt.readline()

        while line !="":
            NumbersOfLines += 1
            TotalNumber += int( line )
            line = NumberTxt.readline()
        averageNumbers = TotalNumber / NumbersOfLines

        print ( "The average is:", averageNumbers)
        print ( "press enter" )

main()
```

Comment: I really don't know how to post on her. However, I'm trying to use Value Error and IOerror in python but my program keeps crashing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please describe how it is crashing, including the complete text of any error messages that are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

With incomplete information, the most likely reason is that because the line you read from file still has the newline character at the end, the very last line is just the newline character `\n`, so the `while` is still true, but then `int("\n")` fails. So, to fix change these two lines:

```
line = NumberTxt.readline().strip() # Strip leading and trailing spaces and newlines

while line: # Not strictly necessary, but more Pythonic to test this way
```